# make: Reference stem of target in prerequisite without patterns

Tags: makefile

I have a project with many .c and .s files. Writing out individual rules for each is a hassle, what I had before for my .c files was this.

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.c %.h
    *recipe*
```

While this works fine for projects with just c source files, it will not work with a project with assembly files.

I've read through the documentation for make on gnu.org and have not been able to figure out a way to reference the stem of the target name or even the whole target name in the prerequisites without using patterns. I would like to do something along these lines.

```
$(C_OBJ_FILES)  : %.c %.h # Where % WOULD be the stem of the target name
$(AS_OBJ_FILES) : %.s     # Where % WOULD be......
```

I currently have separate directories for objects compiled from assembly sources and objects compiled with c sources. While this works, I'd like to have them in the same directory. I also considered creating a hidden symlink that points to the objects directory that I could use to differentiate assembly and c source files, but again, that doesn't solve my question.

Edit: I am not looking for a work around that avoids referencing the target name, since being able to reference it in the prerequisites would help several other parts of my Makefiles. If this is definitely not possible, then say so and that'll answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
C_OBJ_FILES = $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
AS_OBJ_FILES = $(patsubst %.s,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(wildcard *.s))

# static pattern rule for C files
$(C_OBJ_FILES) : $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.c %.h
    <recipe>

# static pattern rule for assembly files
$(AS_OBJ_FILES) : $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.s
    <recipe>
```

In your recipes you can use `$@`, `$<` and `$*`; they will respectively expand as the target (the object file), the first prerequisite (the C or assembly source file) and the stem (the base name of the C or assembly source file). Example:

```
# static pattern rule for C files
$(C_OBJ_FILES) : $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.c %.h
    @echo '[CC] $*' && \
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $< -o $@
```

Comment: I attempted something very similar a couple days ago, it didn't work but I'm guessing I must not have had my $(OBJ_DIR) appended to %.o. I should have probably worked with static pattern rules a little longer before moving on. Reading it now I understand it's the best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach is:

```
all: x.o y.o z.o

%.o: %.s
        *recipe*

%.o: %.c
        *recipe*
```

And then [makedepend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makedepend) can fill in transitive deps, such as C headers. It's not "a hassle" to "write out individual rules", you just let the program do it, automatically.

Your remark about "avoiding referencing the target name" (`$@`) is just bizarre, in a `make` context. You make it sound like you'd rather not express the DAG in a Makefile at all, that you'd rather write a tediously repetitive Bourne script that describes your build process. I encourage you to embrace make [patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html), they're a natural way to express the problem, and will help you describe your requirements in just a few lines of code.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood what I was saying completely. Pleas re-read my question again. I WANT to reference the target name, but $@ does not work properly in the prerequisites.

Comment: But as for your answer, the last time I attempted that, it gave me an error and was trying to look for ASSEMBLYFILE.c instead of ASSEMBLYFILE.s, I have tried it again and strangely, it seems to work. I must have had some other issue at the time, but again, that doesn't answer my question.